# checkbox limit android studio

Tags: java, android

How do i put a limit to check list selection, i only want four as the maximum selection. I've tried following some of the previous solutions you gave but they couldn't work. Your help will be appreciated

```
enter code here
```

public void selectItem1(View view) {

```
    boolean Checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.cbMath:

            if (Checked) {
                selection1.add("Math");
            } else {
                selection1.remove("Math");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cbEnglish:
            if (Checked) {
                selection1.add("English");
            } else {
                selection1.remove("English");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cbChemistry:
            if (Checked) {
                selection1.add("Chemistry");
            } else {
                selection1.remove("Chemistry");
            }
            break;



        case R.id.cbAccounts:
            if (Checked) {
                selection1.add("Accounts");
            } else {
                selection1.remove("Accounts");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cbG_M_D:
            if (Checked) {
                selection1.add("G.M.D");
            } else {
                selection1.remove("G.M.D");
            }
            break;
    }
}
public void final_selection1(View view) {

    String last_Subjects_selection1 = "";
    for (String selections : selection1) {
        last_Subjects_selection1 = last_Subjects_selection1 + selections + "\n";
    }

    Subjects.setText(last_Subjects_selection1);
    Subjects.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to set 'setOnCheckedChangeListener' for checkboxes and create a global var to keep current count of checked items. And if the max value is reached dont set it checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for Switches, it is almost the same as for CheckBoxes:

```
 private final int mMaxCheckedSwitches = 3;
    private int mCurrentCheckedSwitches = 0;

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b && mCurrentCheckedSwitches >= mMaxCheckedSwitches) {
            compoundButton.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        if (b) {
            mCurrentCheckedSwitches += 1;
        }
    }
```